# “What if + (past simple), but (present perfect)?”

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple, conditionals, if

Does it make sense to ask a question like this: “What if you wanted to open the door, but I have taken your keys?”
It’s just an example but is it possible to use this structure? Would it be correct to ask: “What if you (Verb in past simple), but I (Verb in present perfect)?”

Comment: With the first verb in past tense, does it mean anything different from "What if you want to open the door, but I have taken your keys?"

Comment: The tenses are inconsistent in the version as cited. Either use "present tense unreal" *What if you **want** to open the door, but I **have** taken your keys?* or stick with "Past" tense throughout: *What if you **wanted** to open the door, but I **had** taken your keys?* Mixing the tenses like this does happen even among native speakers, but *careful* speakers will certainly notice and avoid it themselves, even if they don't tell *you* when you've got it wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!